# Ship default sublime-settings with package

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

In my `SublimeText` package, I include a file [BlameHighlight.sublime-settings](https://github.com/entrypass/BlameHighlighter/blob/custom-author/BlameHighlight.sublime-settings). During testing, I link from `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages` to this directory, and the changes to this file takes effect.

I also include a Menu item that points to `${packages}/User/BlameHighlight.sublime-settings`. When I use the menu, I see a completely blank file.

How can I use my version of `BlameHighlight.sublime-settings` as the default template for `${packages}/User/BlameHighlight.sublime-settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the same strategy as every other package and not automatically create a copy of the default settings file. Not because I think its better, but because I think the user experience should not differ between the packages.

However as [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615016) stated you have to write our own plugin for this. At least for ST3 this is pretty straight forward:

```py
import os, sublime_plugin, sublime

class CopyUserSettingsCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, package_name, settings_name):
        file_path = os.path.join(sublime.packages_path(), "User", settings_name)
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            try:
                content = sublime.load_resource("Packages/{0}/{1}".format(package_name, settings_name))
                with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                    f.write(content)
            except:
                print("Error copying default settings.")
        self.window.open_file(file_path)
```

Just copy this into a python file in your package and insert in the menu entry:

```js
// ...
{
    "command": "copy_user_settings",
    "args": {
        "package_name": "BlameHighlight",
        "settings_name": "BlameHighlight.sublime-settings"
    },
    "caption": "Settings – User"
},
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically, your `Main.sublime-menu` will contain entries both for your default `.sublime-settings` file (probably `Packages/BlameHighlight/BlameHighlight.sublime-settings`) as well as the `Packages/User` version. If the user wants to customize the settings, they open the default file first (which is read-only in ST3) then the user one, and copy-paste what they need from default to user.

If for some reason you want the user file to be pre-populated with some settings, you'll need to programatically create it.